# SQL Alchemy: Query Filter same field for two data names

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sqlalchemy, filtering, querying

I'm trying to query on a single field for two data types. For example, I want to query the "company" field for two companies, Com_1 and Com_2. I can't figure out by reading the sql alchmey documentation how to do it.

```
    dpl_test = session.query(Exception).filter(Exception.company == "Com_1" or Exception.company == "Com_2").all()
```

This is what I want to do logically but it doesn't return the correct list. This is probably due to my lack of understanding of Sequel programming but filtering on 2 or more data names seems like trival task and am surprised it is not easier to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
# ...

dpl_test = (
    session.query(Exception)
    .filter(or_(Exception.company == "Com_1", Exception.company == "Com_2"))
).all()
```

Read [Conjunctions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/tutorial.html#conjunctions) and [`sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_) for more information.